# Turn script html tag into plain text

Tags: javascript, html

Well, I want to get HTML that is inside pre tags, and turn it into a readable text!

My code is working for most things:

```js
var pre = document.getElementsByTagName("pre");

for(i in pre) {
    pre[i].textContent = pre[i].innerHTML;
}
```

But it doesn't work for script tags, which are loading before they turned into text.
I don't really want to use a whole library to do this, if it is even possible.

E.g. the following alert will be shown despite being within a `<pre>` tag.

```html
<pre>
    <script>window.alert("Test!");</script>
<pre>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does those script manipulate the contents of the `<pre></pre>`?

Comment: I don't think you can prevent `script`-tags from being executed. If `script`-tags are encountered by the browser, it will execute it straight away.

Comment: No, it is something like `<script>alert(321)</script>`, which I don't want to execute, just to show as plain text.

Comment: @BennoZeeman I was wondering, if the script which edits the pre tags, loads first.. There should be a way to prevent the scripts from loading.

Comment: Scripts that are loaded, before tags are ready, cannot reach those specific tags. I think what you want to accomplish is simply not possible. You need to escape the content before it's loaded in the `pre`s somehow.

Answer (score 1):

To make some tag readable, just change `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;`. Browser will not execute any of them and user will still see `<script>alert(321)</script>`.

Comment: May I suggest Regular expressions if you are going to do it this way.

Comment: @PopeyGilbert regular expression or simple replace will do.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. "My code is working for most things". It's working already, except for `script`-tags, as those are being executed before they are changed.

Answer (score 0):

When `script`-tags are encountered, they will be executed. This means that the `script`-tags in the `pre`-tags should be 'escaped' before they are being processed.

One way to do this is to escape the contents of the `pre`s before it's being processed (by `PHP` for example).

You cannot reach the `pre`-tags before they are loaded, and there is no way to prevent the `script`-tags from executing when they have been loaded already.